# python pandas: Flattening a dictionary to a single column

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, pandas

I am writing code to take data from an excel file on an organization's data including divisions and departments -- there is a key:value relationship between div and dept -- and putting it in a template, assigning id numbers for each organization. Division and department are in the same column, their relationship is noted in the "parentID" field, in the example below.

```
id                                               section            parentID    
10000000000 <-company: root level                Company            10000000000 
10010000000 <-division - level 1                 Operations         10000000000 
10010001000 <-department - level 2               Manufacturing      10010000000  
10010001000 <-department - level 2               Distribution       10010000000  
10020000000 <-division - level 1                 Finance            10000000000 
10020001000 <-department - level 2               Payroll            10020000000 
10020002000 <-department - level 2               Accounts Payable   10020000000
```

I have code that generates the ids for divisions by creating a unique list of them and then applying the IDs.

```
df['Division'] .replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
df.dropna(subset=['Division'], inplace=True)
df1 = df[['Division','Department']].drop_duplicates()
df1 = df1.sort_values(by=['Division','Department'],ascending=[True, True])

#get unique list of divisions
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1['Division'].unique())

#set id list for divisions
dfinst = range(len(df2))

for row in df2:    
    iids = dfinst
    sectionID = []
for iid in iids:
    iid = iid +1
    iid = "%02d"%iid 
    inst_ID = '10' + str(iid) + '00000000'
    sectionID.append(inst_ID)
df2['sectionID'] =pd.DataFrame(sectionID)
df2.rename(columns = {0:'cfName'}, inplace = True)
df2['parentID'] = '100000000000'#sets company's id as parent ID for all divisions
```

The following code creates a dictionary of divisions and departments, which I converted to a dataframe:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index(level=1)
df3 = pd.Series(df1['Department'].groupby(df1['Division']))
df3 = df3.to_frame()
```

When I export this to Excel, the dictionary looks like the following(including the spacing):

```
"(u'Operations', 0    Manufacturing1                       Distribution

Name: Division, dtype: object)"
"(u'Finance', 2    Payroll3                       Accounts Payable

Name: Division, dtype: object)"
```

How do I flatten that dictionary so I can get all divisions and departments in the "section" column?

EDIT:

```
(u'Operations', 0    Manufacturing
1                       Distribution
Name: Division, dtype: object)
(u'Finance', 0    Payroll
1                       Accounts Payable
Name: Primary Assignment Center, dtype: object)
```

Comment: Can you post an extract of df3 instead please?

Comment: I added the output from the shell to the original post. See "Edit" at the bottom

Comment: Please post back to the question df3.to_dict().